# Python/Selenium having a very strange interaction with comparing a string that was converted to an integer value

Tags: python, selenium

I'm working on making a script that finds users with less than 5001 followers on instagram in a specific group. The code breaks down and does not work for the first two instances that it is called but then works perfectly fine for all instances after the first two. I have checked the html code, the html code is the same for all users. I am truly at a loss for why it breaks down and does not work for the first two instances that it is called.

Here is the html code:

```
<span class="g47SY ">130</span>
<span class="g47SY " title="1,198">1,198</span>
```

Here is the original code (With the try/except functions removed that enable it to work past the first two instances that it is called):

```
#Finds User Statistics including following/followers
user_stats = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'g47SY ')]")
stat_list = []

for user in user_stats:
    #Gets the string integer values and saves to a list
    stats = user.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    stat_list.append(stats)


#Decides if user has less than 5001 followers
if int(stat_list[1]) <= 5001:
     print("Has less than 5001 followers")
```

With the try/except statements removed here is the error message the I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\Desktop\FINAL - Copy.py", line 91, in follow
    if int(stat_list[1]) <= 5001:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,198'
```

I have tried the following two solutions by converting stat_list to a float or int and vice versa and here are the error messages for those along with the code:

```
if float(int(stat_list[1])) <= 5001:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,198'

if int(float(stat_list[1])) <= 5001:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,198'
```

Comment: `1,198` is not a valid integer number. In some parts of the world, the comma `,`  is used as a visual separator every three decimal places, but you should remove it before trying to convert.

Comment: How would I go about removing the commas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because `,` is getting fetched in the followers number. So you need to first remove that from the count and then put the assert on the number.
You can remove it using:

```
# Put the value which you want to replace in the below code
value.replace(",", "")
```